# Get data of last Month day by day in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, timestamp, sysdate

I want to get data from last month day by day, I can get the last 30 days but I just want the month as it may be less or more than 30 days,

this is the query for getting the last 30 days

```
SELECT Trunc(timestamp),
       Count(*)
FROM   table1
WHERE  Trunc(timestamp) > Trunc(sysdate - 30)
GROUP  BY Trunc(timestamp)
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Also, I am using it in a shell script if I can make a variable in the script and put it the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get data from the start of the current month until today:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(timestamp) AS day,
       COUNT(*)
FROM   table1
WHERE  timestamp >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM')
AND    timestamp <  TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
GROUP BY TRUNC(timestamp)
ORDER BY day
```

To get data from the same day last month until today:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(timestamp) AS day,
       COUNT(*)
FROM   table1
WHERE  timestamp >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -1)
AND    timestamp <  TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
GROUP BY TRUNC(timestamp)
ORDER BY day
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a593380b7c51fc168bacd162913dc82d)*